# After updating Android Studio I got this error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtime-error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
10 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 8 up-to-date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279792/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0